# get key and value from a list with dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dict:

```
dividends=[
    {"2005":0.18},
    {"2006":0.21},
    {"2007":0.26},
    {"2008":0.31},
    {"2009":0.34},
    {"2010":0.38},
    {"2011":0.38},
    {"2012":0.38},
    {"2013":0.38},
    {"2014":0.415},
    {"2015":0.427}
    ]
```

I want to retrieve the key and value to two lists, like:

yearslist = [2005,2006, 2007,2008,2009,2010...]
dividendlist = [0.18,0.21, 0.26....]

any way to implement this?

thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a list of singleton dictionaries instead of just a dictionary with multiple elements?

Comment: Other than with iterating the list and dicts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your dictionaries always have a single key,value pair that you are extracting, you could use two list comprehensions:

```
l1 = [d.values()[0] for d in dividends]
# ['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']

l2 = [d.keys()[0] for d in dividends]
# [0.18, 0.21, 0.26, 0.31, 0.34, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.415, 0.427]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
yearslist = dictionary.keys()
dividendlist = dictionary.values()
```

For both keys and values:

```
items = dictionary.items()
```

Which can be used to split them as well:

```
yearslist, dividendlist = zip(*dictionary.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create two list and append keys in yearlist and values in dividendlist.

here is the code.

```
dividends=[
    {"2005":0.18},
    {"2006":0.21},
    {"2007":0.26},
    {"2008":0.31},
    {"2009":0.34},
    {"2010":0.38},
    {"2011":0.38},
    {"2012":0.38},
    {"2013":0.38},
    {"2014":0.415},
    {"2015":0.427}
    ]

yearlist = []
dividendlist  = []
for dividend_dict in dividends:
    for key, value in dividend_dict.iteritems():
        yearlist.append(key)
        dividendlist.append(value)

print 'yearlist = ', yearlist
print 'dividendlist = ', dividendlist
```

Output:

```
yearlist =  ['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']
dividendlist =  [0.18, 0.21, 0.26, 0.31, 0.34, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.415, 0.427]
```

second way you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
dividends=[
    {"2005":0.18},
    {"2006":0.21},
    {"2007":0.26},
    {"2008":0.31},
    {"2009":0.34},
    {"2010":0.38},
    {"2011":0.38},
    {"2012":0.38},
    {"2013":0.38},
    {"2014":0.415},
    {"2015":0.427}
    ]

yearlist = [dividend_dict.keys()[0] for dividend_dict in dividends]
dividendlist  = [dividend_dict.values()[0] for dividend_dict in dividends]

print 'yearlist = ', yearlist
print 'dividendlist = ', dividendlist
```

Output:

```
yearlist =  ['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']
dividendlist =  [0.18, 0.21, 0.26, 0.31, 0.34, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.415, 0.427]
```

Comment: cool, thanks, that's exactly what I want. do you know any more elegant way?

Comment: Thanks , second way you can use list comprehensions.